# Какие выражения имеют побочные эффекты операторов?

Tags: javascript

```js
  1.  3*4;
  2.  -x;
  3.  y++;
  4.  delete myObject;
  5.  x = 3-4;
  6.  3+4
```

Из языка С известно, что оператор можно себе представить как функцию от операндов. Большинство операторов не изменяет свои операнды, но некоторые, такие как инкремент/декремент (++/--) и присваивание (=), делает это. Про такие операторы говорят, что они обладают побочными эффектами. И если побочный эффект оператора присваивания, заключающийся собственно в присваивании, обычно полезен -- ради него мы этот оператор и используем, то с инкрементом/декрементом дело обстоит не так просто.
С остальными выражениями не всё ясно.

Comment: И? В чём вопрос-то?

Comment: @Alexey Ten Какие выражения имеют побочные эффекты операторов?

Comment: Так вы же их в вопросе и перечислили. Непонятно конечно к чему там философия про полезность.

Comment: @ Alexey Ten у меня сомнения, что все из перечисленных имеют.

Comment: А что считать "побочным"?) Есть ряд особенностей, которые просто нужно знать... например "3" + "4" станет "34". Можно считать побочкой?)

Comment: Ну так все унарные операторы получается с "побочным" эффектом (хотя в их случае, совершенно некорректно называть эффект так)... Разве что кроме оператора `new` - других исключений в голову не приходит. А выражения, они разные бывают (слишком общий вопрос, без уточнения о каких выражениях речь. Если о тех что в вопросе, то 2, 3, 4).

Comment: А, и еще №5, присваивание. Опять же, спорно что его эффект можно называть побочным.

Comment: Давайте еще припомним особенность выражений возвращать результат "влево" - чем это не побочный эффект? По такой логике, "чистых" выражений в JS практически и нет...

Answer (score 0):

```js
  2. --x; 3. y++;
```

Вычисления простых выражений никак не отразятся на состоянии программы и никак не затронут последующие вычисления. Но все операторы, явно или не явно выполняющие операцию присвоения, имеют побочные эффекты. Так как повлияют на результат любого выражения, в котором используется эта переменная или свойство.

Источник: Девид Флэнаган JavaScript. Подробное руководство 6-е издание.стр.87